# Assembly Generating Sound in QtSpim

Tags: audio, assembly, mips, spim

My friends and I are thinking about trying to write a music-composition engine in assembly.  We are required by our course to use QtSpim and wanted to know how to generate sound.  In MARS, Assembly has access to the sound card via syscalls:  http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html

But in QtSpim, the syscall isn't recognized.

Comment: MIPS is a processor architecture, not a hardware thing, so I think you need to be a bit more specific about what hardware you're thinking about running the program on. Some kind of evaluation board or emulator?

Comment: I don't know too much about that because I'm using it in a class, but I'm using QtSpim.

Comment: I know you can do it with MARS http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html
QtSpim doesn't recognize the syscall for that though.